# Python Django website development

Tags: python, django

my code

website/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

music/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import index

 urlpatterns = [

  url('^$', views.index, name='index'),

 ]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse ("This is Music Homepage ")

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'music',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'
```

Problem

```
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current path, music, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: The error does not match your code. Make sure you clear any `.pyc` files and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your `music/urls.py`, should be:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

Answer (score -1):

use in website/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('music.urls')),
]
```

instead of:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

Comment: You should not use `$` together with `include()`.

Comment: [@knbk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2615075/knbk): I am reproduce the above error with sample django project. I have clear my .pyc file. Still I am getting the same error above. Let me clear how to fix properly.